# Specifying the Units in an SVG Path Generator

Tags: html, reactjs, svg, npm, attributes

Due to confidentiality, I cannot get into the specifics of the code I am working with, but I'll do my best to describe the issue I'm having.

My professor made a simple-ish React program that generates and outputs SVGs based on a set of parameters for a microchip manufacturing project. We make use of the Flatten-js npm library to create the svgs, along with some helper functions that cobble everything together. We specify parameters as a number, but the number represents units in microns. We have a save function that downloads the svg from the webpage, which makes use of the Flatten.Polygon.svg() method. The method takes some parameters, but specifying units is not one of them. The SVG looks something like:

```html
<svg>
  <path stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="black" fill-rule="evenodd" fill-opacity="1" d="
M5999.774896627996,6000.3432414235895 L5992.810049576532,6002.509804857073 A0.0338333333333333,0.0338333333333333 0 0,1 5992.789950423468,6002.445192150708 L5999.754797474932,6000.278628717223 A0.04999999999999982,0.04999999999999982 0 0,1 5999.8,6000.25 L6005.7,6000.25 A0.04999999999999982,0.04999999999999982 0 0,1 6005.7,6000.35 L5999.8,6000.35 A0.04999999999999982,0.04999999999999982 0 0,1 5999.774896627996,6000.3432414235895 z
..."></path>
 </svg>
```

The issue is, I need to import the svg into Adobe Illustrator and Fusion 360. When I import them, the SVG works well enough to contain the shapes we predict, but the scaling is wrong. Since the units were meant to be in microns, but F360 works in mm, I expected to have to scale it down to 0.001 the size, but it is way too small when scaled. I'm assuming this has something to do with the program assuming the path's DPI, so in Illustrator I hoped that I could specify PPI manually, but it only has preset values of 72PPI and 300PPI, but the size of the svg in Illustrator is the same regardless of the PPI setting.

To a point, this ceases to be about React, and more about the specifics of html and svg paths, but the program does use React to do what it does. I'm hoping we can do it in code, but if I have to manually edit SVGs I will. Any insight would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: use a transform attribute to set whatever scaling you need.

Comment: "I cannot get into the specifics of the code" - please provide some sample "toy" code then

Comment: Did the _simple-ish React program generates and outputs SVG_ without a viewBox attribute?

Comment: To spell out what @enxaneta probably thinks, a `<svg width="1mm" height="1mm" viewBox="5000 6000 1000 1000">` would identify the userspace units for the path as micron.

Comment: I think we're getting somewhere, but no viewBox attribute was generated. I can put that in manually though. I can specify the viewBox parameter in the svg, but I'm curious about the transform attribute that @RobertLongson referenced. I'll look into these and report back.

Answer (score 0):

> To spell out what @enxaneta probably thinks, a `<svg width="1mm" height="1mm" viewBox="5000 6000 1000 1000">` would identify the
> userspace units for the path as micron.

It turns out that this was most definitely the solution. That, coupled with a transform attribute to scale it from microns to mm. Thank you everyone for the speedy responses!